# Unable to send true/false values for selected radio buttons and should click them twice in order to submit the appropriate values-Angular5 table

Tags: html, typescript, angular5

I'm trying to populate selected values of radio buttons of each row as true or false and form an object to be submitted.
In order to differentiate between the values of radio buttons of each row, value has been given as `{{k}}+{{sizeobj.rbSelected}}` for radio button tag which is causing the problem and updating model as k+false, then k+k+false and so on for successive clicks.
Problem is in the logic in `onSelectionChange(..)` method. onSelectionChange() is supposed to update the JSON with true/false values of selected radio buttons of each row so as to be able to submit the JSON back to server through a POST API service call.

Code:

```
    import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
    import {
        FormsModule, AbstractControl, ControlValueAccessor, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators,
        FormControl, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, Validator, NgForm
    } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        template: `
                  <table>
                  <tbody *ngFor="let redeempointdeliverable of redeempointsdata; let i=index;">
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="allCB[{{i}}]" [checked]="isAllChecked(i)" (change)="checkAll($event, i)"
                                [(ngModel)]="redeempointdeliverable.mainCBChecked" required>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                            <td colspan="6">
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr *ngFor="let catalog of redeempointdeliverable.itemCatalog; let j=index;">
                            <td></td>
                            <td>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <input [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" type="checkbox" value="{{catalog.id}}"
                                [(ngModel)]="catalog.subCBChecked" [checked]="catalog.subCBChecked" (change)="checkSub($event, i, j)"
                                required>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td *ngFor="let sizeobj of catalog.itemSize; let k=index;">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="radio" name={{catalog.itemType}}+{{j}}+{{i}} value={{k}}+{{sizeobj.rbSelected}}
                            [(ngModel)]=sizeobj.rbSelected [checked]="sizeobj.rbSelected"
                            (change)="onSelectionChange($event, i, j, k)"
                            required> &nbsp;&nbsp;{{sizeobj.size}}
                              </div>
                              {{sizeobj.rbSelected}}
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                  `
    })

    export class AppComponent {
        name = 'Angular';
        redeempointsdata: any;

        constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
            this.redeempointsdata = [
                {
                    'itemCatalog': [
                        {
                            'itemSize': [
                                {
                                    'size': 'SMALL',
                                    'rbSelected': false
                                },
                                {
                                    'size': 'MEDIUM',
                                    'rbSelected': false
                                },
                                {
                                    'size': 'LARGE',
                                    'rbSelected': false
                                }
                            ],
                            'subCBChecked': false
                        },
                        {
                            'itemSize': [
                                {
                                    'size': 'SMALL',
                                    'rbSelected': false
                                },
                                {
                                    'size': 'MEDIUM',
                                    'rbSelected': false
                                },
                                {
                                    'size': 'LARGE',
                                    'rbSelected': false
                                }
                            ],
                            'subCBChecked': false
                        },
                        {
                            'itemSize': [
                                {
                                    'size': 'SMALL',
                                    'rbSelected': false
                                },
                                {
                                    'size': 'MEDIUM',
                                    'rbSelected': false
                                },
                                {
                                    'size': 'LARGE',
                                    'rbSelected': false
                                }
                            ],
                            'subCBChecked': false
                        }
                    ],
                    'mainCBChecked': false
                },
                {
                    'itemCatalog': [
                        {
                            'itemSize': [
                                {
                                    'size': 'SMALL',
                                    'rbSelected': false
                                },
                                {
                                    'size': 'MEDIUM',
                                    'rbSelected': false
                                },
                                {
                                    'size': 'LARGE',
                                    'rbSelected': false
                                }
                            ],
                            'subCBChecked': false
                        }
                    ],
                    'mainCBChecked': false
                }
            ];
        }        

        onSelectionChange(ev, i, j, k) {
            this.getItemCatalogs()[i].itemCatalog[j].itemSize[k].rbSelected = ev.target.checked;
            // this.ref.detectChanges();
            for (let l = 0; l < this.redeempointsdata.length; l++) {
                const rpObjAr = this.redeempointsdata[l].itemCatalog;
                for (let m = 0; m < rpObjAr.length; m++) {
                    const sizeAr = rpObjAr[m].itemSize;
                    for (let n = 0; n < sizeAr.length; n++) {
                        const sizeObj = sizeAr[n];
                        console.log('sizeObj.rbSelected = ' + sizeObj.rbSelected);
                        if (n === k) {
                            continue;
                        } else if (n !== k) {
                            this.getItemCatalogs()[i].itemCatalog[j].itemSize[n].rbSelected = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        getItemCatalogs() {
            const rpData = [];
            let rpObj = {};
            for (let i = 0; i < this.redeempointsdata.length; i++) {
                rpObj = this.redeempointsdata[i];
                console.log('rpObj: ' + JSON.stringify(rpObj));
                rpData.push(rpObj);
            }
            console.log('rpData: ' + JSON.stringify(rpData));
            return rpData;
        }

        checkAll(ev, i) {
            let count = 0;
            this.getItemCatalogs()[i].itemCatalog.forEach(x => {
                x.subCBChecked = ev.target.checked;
                if (x.subCBChecked) {
                    count++;
                }
            });
            console.log('count of checkboxes checked: ' + count);
            return count;
        }

        isAllChecked(i) {
            console.log('fired');
            return this.getItemCatalogs()[i].itemCatalog.every(_ => _.subCBChecked);
        }

        checkSub(ev, i, j) {
            let mainCheckVal = true;
            const rpDataAr = this.getItemCatalogs();
            const x = rpDataAr[i].itemCatalog;
            for (j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
                if (x[j].subCBChecked === true) {
                    mainCheckVal = mainCheckVal && x[j].subCBChecked;
                } else {
                    mainCheckVal = false;
                }
            }
            this.getItemCatalogs()[i].mainCBChecked = mainCheckVal;
            console.log('mainCheckVal: ' + mainCheckVal);
            return mainCheckVal;
        }
    }
```

I'm now able to populate appropriate values of true or false for the selected radio buttons in the JSON object with the above code changes, as can be verified in the below link, but still faced with a problem, i.e., need to click each radio button twice in order to select it. Appreciate any help in resolving this issue.

Working Plunker link:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Nwz96APdaXdOXUuZ?preview

Image link of mock screen:
[Nested Table with checkbox and a set of radio buttons for each row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t00xz.png)

P.S.: I would need this with the above JSON or data model (or, if not, with minimum possible changes to it as its difficult to get it changed) which is obtained through a service call from back-end.

Comment: Can you please be a little more precise what the outcome of onSelectionChange() is supposed to be?

Comment: @DiabolicWords, Thanks for responding. I've updated the question with the requirement. Please verify.

Comment: Just to get you right. Yo want to set the state of rbSelected  manually? May I ask why? Due to `[(ngModel)]="sizeobj.rbSelected"` you already change the value directly in the object. Are you aware of this? Or is there still something you want to achieve that I overlooked?

Comment: Yes, I want to set the state of `rbSelected` manually in my component, as, the values of `value="{{k}}+{{sizeobj.rbSelected}}"` of each radio button, viz., `k+false` or `k+k+false` and so on are getting set into their `[(ngModel)]` for each click which is not what I want, I want `[(ngModel)]` value or JSON object value to be submitted to contain `'rbSelected': true` if selected and `'rbSelected': false` if not, and not as below: `'rbSelected': 0+false` if 0th column radio button is selected and `'rbSelected': false` if not, which is what is happening currently.

Comment: Sorry, but I can see now, that my first solutions both were wrong. I'll try to show up by tomorrow with a final and fitting solution.

Comment: Hey, that is alright, you're trying so much to help resolve my issue, immensely appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the original issue with my code. Here is the fix in 2 steps:

i. The way `ngModel` is placed in below snippet without being assigned any values like before `[(ngModel)]=sizeobj.rbSelected` allows it to override the values being passed to it from the `value={{k}}+{{sizeobj.rbSelected}}` attribute and properly assign selected values to `sizeobj.rbSelected` of our JSON object.

```
<input type="radio" name={{catalog.itemType}}+{{j}}+{{i}} value={{k}}+{{sizeobj.rbSelected}}
    [checked]="sizeobj.rbSelected" (change)="onSelectionChange($event, i, j, k)"
    ngModel required>
```

ii. Inside `onSelectionChange()` method, we need to assign values to our selected radio button location directly from the `event` object parameter passed to it by `(change)` event handler as shown in below snippet:

```
onSelectionChange(ev, i, j, k) {
    this.getItemCatalogs()[i].itemCatalog[j].itemSize[k].rbSelected = ev.target.checked;
..
}
```

Rest all the code remains the same. Here is the working Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Nwz96APdaXdOXUuZ

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here you go. I think I've got a solution for you.

To achieve your goal you have to temporarily add an additional field to your object structure for the RadioButton-Interaction. This field get's kicked before transmitting the object back to server in order to not cause any parser exceptions.

> **FIRST**: We add a new field when the system comes up and call this field
>   **sharedValue**

To achieve this put the following method into your typescript-file

```
private addFieldSharedValue(): void {
    for (let l = 0; l < this.redeempointsdata.length; l++) {

        const rpObjAr = this.redeempointsdata[l].itemCatalog;

        for (let m = 0; m < rpObjAr.length; m++) {
            // adding the field 'sharedValue' to each catalogue
            rpObjAr[m].sharedValue = '0';
        }
    }

    // debugging: printing a clone to show the intermediate state of the object
    console.log('before: ', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.redeempointsdata)));
}
```

By adding the field sharedValue I set it to zero by default. If you do not assign a value this is no problem. Then the initial value is undefined and no radio button in a group is preselected.

Call this method once at the very end of the constructor (after the instantiation of *`redeempointsdata`*) or simply in the ngOnInit()-method.

> **SECOND**: We bind each radio button of a group to this field instead of binding it
>   to its own **rbSelected**-field. 
>   The **value**-field of your radio button in the HTML-Template gets initially the value of *`k`*.

```
<td *ngFor="let sizeobj of catalog.itemSize; let k=index;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="radio" name={{catalog.itemType}}+{{j}}+{{i}} value={{k}}
           [(ngModel)]="catalog.sharedValue" [checked]="catalog.sharedValue"
           (change)="onSelectionChange($event, i, j, k)"
        required> 
        &nbsp;&nbsp;{{sizeobj.size}}
    </div>
    {{sizeobj.rbSelected}}
</td>
```

What happens now is, that the radio buttons of a group only change the value of sharedValue in order to work properly together, whereas your `onSelectionChange()`-method now is able to perform as intended. Because it now is the only one to change the field `rbSelected` of each radio button.

> **THIRD**: If you've done your selections and want to persist the object, you have to **drop sharedValue** beforehand. Call this method to get it done.

```
private deleteFieldSharedValue() {
    for (let l = 0; l < this.redeempointsdata.length; l++) {

        const rpObjAr = this.redeempointsdata[l].itemCatalog;

        for (let m = 0; m < rpObjAr.length; m++) {
            // delete the field 'sharedValue' of each catalogue
           delete rpObjAr[m].sharedValue;
        }
    }
    // debugging: printing the final state of the object before sending it
    console.log('after: ', this.redeempointsdata);
}
```

> **FOURTH**: Call your persist- / save- / store- or whatever it is called method to send the object back to the server.

That's it.

Comment: Okay, this is working now. I tested it several times locally. Hope this finally solves your issue.

Comment: I'd really appreciate if you would upvote this answer and mark it as solution, if this is what you were searching for. Thx in advance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hack logic, its working! :) I've upvoted your answer, which got recorded, but won't reflect on this site due to my insufficient points/reputation. Also, I don't see any option to accept your solution.

Meanwhile, I've found out the original issue with my code, and I've posted it as an answer, hope you can review and upvote it too :)